# move text from one line to previous line

Tags: perl

Hi I have the following file:

```
a,b,
c
d,e,
f
g,h,
i
```

where I need the file to look like:

```
a,b,c
d,e,f
h,h,i
```

i.e move every cell in an even line to the previous line.

Anyone have a Perl one-liner for this?

Comment: i would call it "remove the newline at each odd line"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing newlines at each odd lines, as suggested by @Paulchenkiller

```
perl -i -ne 'chomp if $. % 2 == 1; print' input.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If it really is based off of paired lines:

```
perl -i -pe 'chomp if $. % 2' input.txt
```

If the distinction is the ending comma:

```
perl -i -pe 'chomp if /,$/' input.txt
```